# Liferay, how to initiate the certain web content in Velocity

Tags: liferay, velocity, webcontent

I've been playing around of this issue for awhile now and can't get my head wrapped around of it. I'm using Liferay 6.1 CE GA2.

**Goal:**

User editable content, for example footer in each page. I've created the web content which id is 12701.

**Method**:

```
#set ($local_temp_content = $journalContentUtil.getContent($scope_group_id, "12701", null, "$locale", $theme_display))
$local_temp_content<br />
```

**Issue:**
It won't return anything sensible. It's just printing "$local_temp_content" as the result.

Any pointers how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a velocity macro to retrieve a web content by ID from local scope first and then by global scope:

```
#macro(glarticle $temp_article_id)

    #set ($temp_content = "")

    #set ($scope_group_id = $theme_display.scopeGroupId)
    #set ($global_group_id = $theme_display.companyGroupId)

    #set ($temp_content = $journalContentUtil.getContent($scope_group_id, $temp_article_id, null, "$locale", $theme_display))
    #set ($temp_content = "$!{temp_content}")

    #if ($temp_content.length() == 0)
        #set ($temp_content = $journalContentUtil.getContent($global_group_id, $temp_article_id, null, "$locale", $theme_display))
    #end

    $!{temp_content}
#end
```

How to use it:

```
#glarticle('1234')
```

Comment: This seems to work nicely and bringing the content. I'm trying to make it a bit more usable for user thus I used Tejas Kanami's snippet from: http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2013/05/embed-selected-web-content-in-liferay.html#comment-form.

I still have an issue with this. I can't initiate multiple instances on the same page, since it's rendering the same content on each portlet. I've tried different instance IDs but it doesn't seem to affect on the business.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging velocity try outputting every part of your call.

```
scope_group_id = $scope_group_id<br>
theme_display = $theme_display<br>
journalContentUtil = $journalContentUtil<br>
```

If you get exactly what you wrote than that variable is not available.
If all are resolved then possibilitis are:

- wrong article id
- there was exception during article rendering (you should check log)